# Ragged tensors as input for LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Learning about ragged tensors and how can I use them with tensorflow.
My example

```
xx = tf.ragged.constant([
                        [0.1, 0.2],
                        [0.4, 0.7 , 0.5, 0.6]
                        ])
yy = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1,0,0]])

mdl = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[None], batch_size=2, dtype=tf.float32, ragged=True),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64),  
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

mdl.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

mdl.summary()
history = mdl.fit(xx, yy, epochs=10)
```

The error

```
Input 0 of layer lstm_152 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [2, None]
```

I am not sure if I can use ragged tensors like this. All examples I found have embedding layer before LSTM, but what I don't want to create additional embedding layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to use **Input** layer rather than **InputLayer**, you often not need to use **InputLayer**, Anyway the probelm that the shape of your input and LSTM layer input shape was wrong , here the modification i have made with some comments.

---

```
# xx should be 3d for LSTM
xx = tf.ragged.constant([
                        [[0.1, 0.2]],
                        [[0.4, 0.7 , 0.5, 0.6]]
                        ])

"""
Labels represented as OneHotEncoding so you 
should use CategoricalCrossentropy instade of SparseCategoricalCrossentropy
"""

yy = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1,0,0]])

# For ragged tensor , get maximum sequence length
max_seq = xx.bounding_shape()[-1]

mdl = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Input Layer with shape = [Any,  maximum sequence length]                      
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[None, max_seq], batch_size=2, dtype=tf.float32, ragged=True),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

# CategoricalCrossentropy
mdl.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

mdl.summary()
history = mdl.fit(xx, yy, epochs=10)
```

Comment: I've tried your solution considering a ragged tensor of ECG sequences with variable length. I've paid attention to batch_size =1 but I got an error about matrix size incompatibility. It seems that the length of the next sequence is considerer with the previous sequence. 
Here's the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66186241/matrix-size-incompatibility-with-ragged-tensor-of-variable-size-sequence-and-lst Can you help me ?