# Matrix Size Incompatibility with ragged tensor of variable size sequence and LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm working on ECG classification using LSTM. I have about thousands of ECG sequences, but the length of each ECG sequence seems to be different.

The model I have built is inspired of  :

[LSTM Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62031683/ragged-tensors-as-input-for-lstm)

Actually I have a ragged tensor of 8528 sequences (Z) which has a shape of (8528, None, None), and corresponding labels (U with 4 possibilities) are a one hot encoded tensor of shape (8528, 4).

The model is supposed to be a sequence of LTSM with respectively 64,256 and 100 units followed by a Dense layer of 4.

I have understand that because of the variable sequence length, the batch_size has to be set to 1.

Here is the code I'm using :

```
    max_seq = Z.bounding_shape()[-1]
    print(f'Maximum length sequence : {max_seq}')
    
    model = keras.Sequential([
                              tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[None, max_seq], batch_size=1, dtype=tf.float32, ragged=True),
                              keras.layers.LSTM(units=64, activation='tanh', dropout=0.2, name = 'LSTM_1', return_sequences=True),
                              keras.layers.LSTM(units=256, activation='tanh', dropout=0.2, name = 'LSTM_2',return_sequences=True),
                              keras.layers.LSTM(units=100, activation='tanh', dropout=0.2, name = 'LSTM_3', return_sequences=False),
                              # tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4),
                              #tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name = 'Flatten'),
                              tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4, activation='sigmoid', name = 'Dense_1')
    ])
    
    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
    
    

model.fit(Z, W, batch_size=1, epochs=20)
```

That returns :

```
Maximum length sequence : 18286
Model: "sequential_23"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
LSTM_1 (LSTM)                (1, None, 64)             4697856   
_________________________________________________________________
LSTM_2 (LSTM)                (1, None, 256)            328704    
_________________________________________________________________
LSTM_3 (LSTM)                (None, 100)               142800    
_________________________________________________________________
Dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 404       
=================================================================
Total params: 5,169,764
Trainable params: 5,169,764
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Size of first sequence : 9000
```

But I got this error about Matrix incompatibility :

```
Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,16866], In[1]: [18286,256]
     [[{{node sequential_23/LSTM_1/while/body/_1/sequential_23/LSTM_1/while/lstm_cell_67/MatMul}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_100065]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Can someone explain me why I got such type of error ?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT : Here's a minimal reproductible example :**

```
xx = tf.ragged.constant([
                        [[0.1, 0.2]],
                        [[0.4, 0.7 , 0.5, 0.6]],
                         [[0.4, 0.7 , 0.5]]
                        
                        ])

"""
Labels represented as OneHotEncoding so you 
should use CategoricalCrossentropy instade of SparseCategoricalCrossentropy
"""

yy = np.array([[0, 0, 1,0], [1,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0]])


model = keras.Sequential([
                          tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[None, max_seq], batch_size=1, dtype=tf.float32, ragged=True),
                          keras.layers.LSTM(units=64, activation='tanh', dropout=0.2, name = 'LSTM_1', return_sequences=True),
                          keras.layers.LSTM(units=256, activation='tanh', dropout=0.2, name = 'LSTM_2',return_sequences=True),
                          keras.layers.LSTM(units=100, activation='tanh', dropout=0.2, name = 'LSTM_3', return_sequences=False),
                          tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4, activation='sigmoid', name = 'Dense_1')
])

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()


model.fit(xx, yy, batch_size=1, epochs=20)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've just added a minimum reproductible example below the edit of my question.
Thanks for your help

Comment: You can't specify the batch-size twice just remove it from `model.fit(...)` method, `model.fit(xx, yy, epochs=20)`.

Comment: It seems to be working with the MRE as a toy example, but still hvae the samed error with my real datset

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not will be able to deduce what might causes this error,  You might check why bounded shape is a `None` for some reason ragged tensor won't be able to parse your sequences, `(8528, None, None)`, or share the dataset source, I might check it if I can.

Comment: Here's the repo with the notebook and files (full dataset can be found at the google drive url mentionned in the notebook).
https://github.com/sebgra/Arrythmia_Classification
 The fitting of the model is functionnal with a partial dataset (Database) but still sendind error with th full dataset (Cardiology_Dataset)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've made a for loop in which i take the i-th first lines of my dataset and feed it to the model (ragged tensor format, and one hot encoding for the labels).
It starts to bug at the 33th step (33 first dataset lines) and then continue to be functional until a dataset of about 300 lines.
I've also set the shuffle argument to False. I've checked, there are no Nan or None in my dataset. I'm still confused with this issue.
Any idea ?