# ValueError:Input 0 of layer lstm_45 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, None, None, 128)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm new to deep learning and have a problem with understanding embedding and passing sequence of 4 feature vectors (all floats) to an LSTM model. My model looks as following:

```
f_data = np.array([[[259992.7, 11745.7, 0.0, 5500.0], [259068.5, 11745.7, 0.0, 5500.0]], [[250284.9, 11713.07, 1.0, 5730.0], [259043.3, 11728.2, 0.0, 5615.0], [238096.3, 11680.1, 0.0, 5730.0]]], dtype=object) 
y_data = np.array([0,1])
train_x = tf.ragged.constant(f_data)

keras_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[None], dtype=tf.float64, ragged=True),
tf.keras.layers.Embedding(260000, 12),
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, use_bias=False, input_shape=(None, 4)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(32),
tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)])
keras_model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', 
loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

keras_model.fit(train_x, y_data, epochs=100, batch_size=32)
```

I also had troubles with passing sequences of different length but ragged input solved it. This is the error I'm getting:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_45 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, None, None, 128)

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear. Your input does not match the expected input shape. Either correct your shape of inputs, or change the input layer's shape parameter in `keras_model`

Comment: Where should I change shape of my inputs? `tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[None, 4], dtype=np.float64, ragged=True)` produces `ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_65 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, None, 4, 128)` error

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. On my machine this compiles just fine. Mind you tell us if you use conda, pip? Versions of tensorflow/keras?

Comment: Sure I am using 2.6.0 tensorflow, 2.6.0 keras So basically `keras_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[None, 4], dtype=np.float64, ragged=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10001,128),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, use_bias=False, input_shape=(None, 4)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32),
    tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)
])` this works for you?

Comment: FYI - Sequential model doesn't need an input layer you can remove this

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62031683/ragged-tensors-as-input-for-lstm) SO answer for ragged tensor input in your LSTM.

Answer (score 0):

tf.keras.layers.LSTM layer expects input of shape 3D tensor with shape `[batch, timesteps, feature]`. In this case you are feeding 4D array.
Change the input shape,

By removing embedding layer its working,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
f_data = np.array([[[259992.7, 11745.7, 0.0, 5500.0], [259068.5, 11745.7, 0.0, 5500.0]], [[250284.9, 11713.07, 1.0, 5730.0], [259043.3, 11728.2, 0.0, 5615.0], [238096.3, 11680.1, 0.0, 5730.0]]], dtype=object) 
y_data = np.array([0,1])
train_x = tf.ragged.constant(f_data)
keras_model = tf.keras.Sequential([

tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32,use_bias=False, input_shape = (None,4)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(32),
tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])
keras_model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', 
loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

keras_model.fit(train_x, y_data, epochs=100, batch_size=32)
keras_model.summary()
```