# How to shape input for Ragged tensor with LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm getting the following error when I try to pass multiple ragged tensors to my model:

```
ValueError: Layer "sequential_3" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors
```

I suspect it has something to do with the "[shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62031683/ragged-tensors-as-input-for-lstm)" argument in the `Input` layer of the model.

Yes, I've reviewed the ragged tensor documentation.
Yes, I've spent many hours scouring the Google-net.
Yes, I've browsed stackoverflow.com related articles.
Yes, I'm most likely noobing it up right now and there is a simple solution.

Below is a **reproducible** example
(tensorflow 2.7; keras 2.7; python 3.7)

**dependencies**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import keras
import keras.layers
```

**Dummy Dataset**

```
d0 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "id":[
        1,
        2, 2,
        3, 3, 3,
        4, 4, 4, 4,
        5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
        6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6
    ],
    "date":[
        pd.to_datetime("2008-03-31"),
        pd.to_datetime("2008-03-31"), pd.to_datetime("2008-06-30"),
        pd.to_datetime("2008-03-31"), pd.to_datetime("2008-06-30"), pd.to_datetime("2008-09-30"),
        pd.to_datetime("2008-03-31"), pd.to_datetime("2008-06-30"), pd.to_datetime("2008-09-30"), pd.to_datetime("2008-12-31"),
        pd.to_datetime("2008-03-31"), pd.to_datetime("2008-06-30"), pd.to_datetime("2008-09-30"), pd.to_datetime("2008-12-31"), pd.to_datetime("2009-03-31"),
        pd.to_datetime("2008-03-31"), pd.to_datetime("2008-06-30"), pd.to_datetime("2008-09-30"), pd.to_datetime("2008-12-31"), pd.to_datetime("2009-03-31"), pd.to_datetime("2009-06-30")
    ],
    "date2":[
        1,
        1, 2,
        1, 2, 3,
        1, 2, 3, 4,
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
    ],
    "input":[
        10,
        11, 12,
        13, 14, 15,
        16, 17, 18, 19,
        20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
        25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
    ],
    "target":[
        60,
        61, 62,
        63, 64, 65,
        66, 67, 68, 69,
        70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 
        75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80
    ],
})
```

**inputs**

```
inputs = []
inputs.append(tf.ragged.constant(d0.groupby("id")["input"].apply(list)))
inputs.append(tf.ragged.constant(d0.groupby("id")["date2"].apply(list)))
```

**target**

```
target = tf.ragged.constant(d0.groupby("id")["target"].apply(list))
```

**model**

```
mod1 = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 4), dtype=tf.float32, batch_size=1, ragged=True),
    keras.layers.LSTM(units=32, dtype=tf.float32, return_sequences=True, use_bias=False),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=32),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])
```

**compile**

```
mod1.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="mse",
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)
```

**fit**

```
history = mod1.fit(
    x=inputs,
    y=target,
    epochs=1
)
```

The error occurs during the `fit` step.